# Image Icons like Macbook in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for very simple UI; with three Image Icons on Bottom of the screen. And when user hovers over that Image Icon it pops out and come bigger then normal size when no mouse over the Image.

Exactly like Mac where they have list of Icons on the bottom and when you hover over one Icon it stands out and when you click on it it opens respective application...

How can I do this in WPF C# ?

Or if you can direct me to existing example/code etc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `Fish Eye Effect` in *WPF*.

Here is a good article from CodeProject:

[FishEyePanel/FanPanel - Examples of custom layout panels in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Panels.aspx)

Comment: And I am also looking for effect of reflection of Image; i.e. Image would be reflected below; like mirror image. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [user control](http://huydinhpham.blogspot.com/2008/12/wpf-animated-dashboard.html) that would mimic the dashboard of the Mac's (Fish eye effect).